Assign more than one core per MPI process in mpirun
I'm a bit new to MPI and parallel processing. I've been running a job in an HPC environment in which I can use up to 160 physical cores. However, increasing the number of MPI process to match the number of available physical cores (i.e. mpirun -n 160) often leads to a prterun signal 9 (Killed) error, which I suspect is being caused by memory issues. Therefore, I always have to decrease the number of MPI processes to around 64 processes (i.e. mpirun -n 64), which solves the job with no error.
I have two questions:

By running mpirun -n 64 in an environment with 160 physical cores available, will MPI still efficiently use the remaining cores to support the computation on the 64 parallel processes?
If not, how I can assign in mpirun more than one physical core per MPI process, in a way I don't exceed the maximum of 64 process parallelization?

I had searched a bit about it, and this thread seems to be related to my question, but I still didn't exactly understood how to apply it for my case. I would really appreciate your comments on this.

First you need to make sure your application can efficiently more than one core per MPI task (e.g. hybrid parallelization, typically MPI+OpenMP). Then tell mpi or the resource manager how many MPI tasks you want to run and how many cores should be allocated to each MPI task. Unless your app works best when the number of MPI tasks is a power of two, you can start with 40 MPI tasks and 4 cores per MPI task in order to use all the 160 available physical cores. If Open MPI and mpirun, you could mpirun -np 40 --map-by node:PE=4 ....

@GillesGouaillardet Thank you for your insight, it's clearer for me now! I was indeed suspecting my program would have to be compatible to allow more cores per MPI process... Unfortunately I don't think it's the case. I'll probably stay with the 64 process until I upgrade it to allow hybrid parallelization.

Check your compiler and the libraries you are using. If your app does a lot of BLAS, then it can take advantage of the extra cores. Same if your compiler can do automatic (multi-threaded) parallelization.
